# Unable to locate elements with CSSpath in IE though the same is working fine with FF for Selenium WebDriver with Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

The following is the syntax of my code using in IE:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#loginForm>div>table>tbody>tr:nth-child(4)>div>span>span>span")
```

The error is:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with css selector == #loginForm>div>table>tbody>tr:nth-child(4)>div>span>span>span (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 594 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.31.0', revision: '1bd294d', time: '2013-02-27 20:53:56'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_17'
Session ID: f0058b48-ac08-4623-9920-5a871ce43605
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, elementScrollBehavior=0, javascriptEnabled=true, enablePersistentHover=true, ignoreZoomSetting=false, browserName=internet explorer, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss, version=8, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, allowAsynchronousJavaScript=true, requireWindowFocus=false, handlesAlerts=true, initialBrowserUrl=, nativeEvents=true, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

Can anybody please help on this?

Comment: You don't say what version of IE you're running into this on, but it's IE8 or below, CSS3 selectors (like `nth-of-type`) aren't valid.

Comment: @JimEvans is right, but on top of this, even if we did want to help you with your CSS, you must provide the target HTML. The Error states that Selenium was unable to find the Element on the page, which is currently a direct result of an incorrect CSS locator.

Comment: Hi, sorry forgot to mention the IE version is 8.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have said, CSS3 selectors won't work on IE8 or below, such as `nth-child`.

I look to the below site in times like this, to see what is supported and what is not:

http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child

As for the next step, I'd do two things:

Run the latest version of Selenium.

Change your locator to something like, (not tested since you haven't provided your HTML):

```
//*[@id='loginForm']/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/div/span/span/span
```

Comment: WebElement signin_button= driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("//*[@id='loginForm']/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/div/span/span/span")); Still the same error occured.

Comment: It's XPath, you'll need `WebElement signin_button= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='loginForm']/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/di‌​v/span/span/span"));`

Comment: Well that's because your simple snippet above is a) incomplete and b) doesn't even match your *original* selector, so mine isn't going to either. Please provide all the HTML required around the element you need.

Comment: Thanx it is solved. Used Cssselector and it identified the element.

Answer (score -1):

```
The Html code is as follows.
<form name="loginForm" id="loginForm" action="/suredesign/j_spring_security_check" method="post">
<div class="dijitLayoutContainer dijitContainer dijitTableLayout" id="dojox_layout_TableContainer_0" data-dojo-props="cols:1,spacing:10,showLabels:false" data-dojo-type="dojox.layout.TableContainer" widgetId="dojox_layout_TableContainer_0">
<table width="100%" class="tableContainer-table tableContainer-table-horiz" cellSpacing="10">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td class="tableContainer-valueCell">
<div title="" class="dijitContentPane" id="dijit_layout_ContentPane_17" role="group" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" widgetId="dijit_layout_ContentPane_17">
<span class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitButton paddingright5 signInLabel" role="presentation" widgetId="dijit_form_Button_0">
dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonNode
```

Comment: @shravi: when you reply to a comment, you should reply as another comment, not as an answer. Or even better, you should edit your question to include the new information.